# Pros and cons of big data and small data?

Tags: bigdata

I'm looking for more in depth answers. I know the basics--small data is quicker to analyze, you'll have more power with big data, etc. But I'd like to know more (maybe about causal inference?) about the benefits and drawbacks of each. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Large data tends to be preferable to small data, since the larger samples you have, the more precise your estimates will be. There are a few benefits of small data. For instance, visualization, inspection and understanding what's going on in the data is much easier with small data than with large data. If you have 20 000 observations and 50 variables, it's not easy to look at the data manually, so to speak, whereas 10 observations on 2 variables is much easier. Furthermore, if a dataset is extremely large, many statistical methods can break down in the sense that they take too long time to run for them to be reasonable.

On the flip-side, small datasets will lead to lower precision in your estimates, lower power and have a much larger risk that comparison groups by chance differ on some important background characteristics, that make comparisons between the groups unfair, even if the data is from a randomized trial. To me, these drawbacks outweigh the benefits of having a small dataset.

Furthermore, if you have a large dataset, evaluation of your models is easier, as you can split your data into training and evaluation sets. This means that you can test your model on data that was not used to estimate its parameters. If your dataset is small, this might not be possible since every observation is important then for estimation of the parameters. Leave-one-out cross validation is an option, but there will be high dependency between the tests.

From a causal inference point of view, it is also a question of how the data was generated. Very big data tends to be of observational kind (registers, for instance) and thus generally have the problems associated with non-randomized studies, especially confounding (i.e. the outcomes for the treatment and control groups not being comparable without adjustment for confounders). This is not saying that data from experimental studies are without their problems or that observational data is useless (far from it!), but one should always be aware of which type of data one has at hand. Of course, a large observational dataset is preferable to a small observational dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Big data is indeed known to be a more precise version of data analysis and helps businesses with increased efficiency, improved performance, reduced pricing resulting in high sales and better marketing.

However, most often, so is not the case.

Big data requires a large amount of data collection, well-equipped infrastructure, and a strong team of data scientists who can understand your company's goal and help you with precise data analysis.

On the other hand, small data does not require large infrastructure or a team of data scientists to run data models. Thereby, it cuts the cost on unnecessary expensive tech teams.

Speaking of accuracy, small data works better since it reckons the smallest bits of your business and offers you hyper-personalized solutions.

Often companies fail to realize the goals and how to actualize them through big data. With a large amount of data collection, the true purpose of data analysis is likely to get buried under the huge data that it is.

Contrarily, using small data, companies can solve the company's tiniest and most hidden problems.

Big data may be beneficial for large organizations and tech giants; small data can be leveraged by startups and SMEs who are looking to get 'smarter' with their decisions.